# unterminated string literal when I click on anchor tag

Tags: html, onclick, anchor

When I click on a tag getting below error

unterminated string literal

```html
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'CloudStore', 'Click', 'Cloud  is here - Banner’);" href="about.php" class="red-text block">Read more</a>
```

Comment: you have `'Cloud  is here - Banner’` that's why it shows error.

Comment: This is required for SEO

Comment: I mean, check your string literal. It is *"`"*

Answer (score 0):

In last parameter string, you have `backtick` instead of `single quote`

> 'Cloud  is here - Banner’ <- see the string ending literal

[image]

Just use 'Cloud  is here - Banner'

```js
function ga() {

}
```

```html
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'CloudStore', 'Click', 'Cloud  is here - Banner');" href="#" class="red-text block">Read more</a>
```

Comment: Both links are identical except href

Comment: @Shreya No not identical. Copy & paste and see in notepad.

Comment: <a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'CloudStore', 'Click', 'Cloud  is here - Banner’);" href="about.php" class="red-text block">Read more</a>
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'CloudStore', 'Click', 'Cloud  is here - Banner');" href="#" class="red-text block">Read more</a>

Comment: See where are difference

Comment: @Shreya Check above image, you will see "Ending literal" is different

Comment: @Shreya You have `backtick` key in a string ending.